# How do I get rid of this Anthy toolbar?

Tags: keyboard, input-method

I toggle between writing in Japanese and English on my computer, usitng Anthy and iBus. I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on two computers, and set up my language input options the same as I have for years, and for the most part it works fine and I have all the functionality I wan

The only problem is that on one of the computers, my laptop, whenever I switch to Anthy to input Japanese, this floating toolbar pops up just under where I'm typing'

[image: anthy floating toolbar]

I can' find any option for getting rid of this thing. It doesn't show up on my desktop computer, so I know it doesn't have to be there for Anthy to work.

How do I get rid of this toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Setup - IBus-Anthy` either via the third button on the bar you want to get rid of, or via `Dash > Text Entry > [single click] Japanese Anthy > [click on settings bottom right]`.

You can choose what parts of the menu should display next to your cursor, when Anthy is active, in the settings's `General` tab under `Menu visibility on Status Icon`. Uncheck all boxes (in your case `Input mode`, `Dictionary mode`, `Preferences - Anthy`) and the menu should disappear.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Sorry, though, I should have mentioned I'm using Gnome-Flashback. I don't seem to have a `Setup - Ibus-Anthy` anywhere that I can see. I was able to uncheck the options on `Menu visibility on Status Icon`, but the toolbar is still there.

Comment: I had the same problem when updating to ubuntu 14.04 (with unity). For me it disappeared after unchecking these options and restarting Anthy. `Setup - Ibus-Anthy` is the name of the window, which is the preferences window for Anthy. If you managed to uncheck the boxes, I guess you found it. Can you check, whether the menu is still there after a reboot?

Comment: This might have worked. After a reboot, I stopped seeing the toolbar on my laptop. Oddly, I started seeing it on my desktop. In any case, I'm going to confirm my settings on both machines and then hopefully come back here to mark this as correct.

Comment: If you're reading this in 2017 or later, you should probably try [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/962383/744383) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `System Settings -> Text Entry` and select Anthy, you can click the toolkit icon to reach the Anthy Setup dialog. Possibly (I don't really know) it includes a way to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer (Earthliŋ's) is not correct - or at least not accurate anymore in 2017.

Whether or not the popup (misleadingly called the "property panel" by IBus) appears is not controlled by IBus-Anthy but IBus itself. The `Menu visibility on Status Icon` checkboxes in IBus-Anthy only controls what appears *on* the popup. Unchecking them all creates a zero-width popup, that seems to have the unfortunate side effect of breaking keyboard input conversion (e.g., zenkaku/henkaku) altogether.

The actual solution to OP's problem is simply to open `IBus Preferences` (right-click on the IBus task bar panel icon), and at `Show property panel:` to select the `Do not show` dropdown option.

Comment: The question asks about ubuntu 14.04. Maybe you could add what version of ubuntu your answer refers to. 17.04?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Honestly, none. I use Arch. Just found this question because I had the same problem as OP. I can't imagine Ubuntu doing anything particularly distribution-specific with IBus/Anthy though?